# How to configure webpack for path resolver to use dependency which is an internal dependency of another dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a project (named xProject) setup as depicted in images below. As we can see a module named `utils.js` under `commons/` is importing `uuid` module but it is not installed as a dependency in `commons/pacakge.json`. I have added `commons` as dependency in `web/package.json`: `"commons": "file:../commons"`. When I import `utils.js` into a module `MyModule.tsx` under `web/`, it complains about following ERROR:

```
ERROR in ../commons/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uuid' in '/Users/xuser/myfolder/xproject/commons/'
```

**I want webpack to use `uuid` from other dependencies whose internal dependency is 'uuid'. Is it possible? If yes, how? For example, `node-sass` is a package which has `uuid` as an internal dependency.**

I did look for the solution whole last day but unfortunately I didn't get it working.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]